# pseudospectral two time scales

Tags: dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, optimal-control

I am using pseudospectral methods for solving optimal control problems.
My problem is that I am having two different dynamic systems with two different final time (initial time could be common for both: tI = 0, or not)

I need to add a constraint comparing two states variables at the same time, any ideas? I can compare it for the same time in the (-1,1) scale, but I don´t know how I can do it in the total time scale.

Thank you, 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to model the problem as a multi-phase optimal control problem with two phases. In the first phase both dynamical systems are active. Since this phase has the same duration for both dynamical systems, you can compare their state variables in the pseudospectral framework without time inconsistency. In the second phase only one dynamical system is still evolving.

Best regards,